Trouble Accessing AG Grid Data with Selenium Due to DOM Virtualization
I'm facing an issue while trying to automate a table built with AG Grid using Selenium. The data I'm attempting to access isn't loading in the DOM due to AG Grid's DOM virtualization feature. As a result, the rows are not visible in the DOM, making it challenging to interact with or extract the data using Selenium.
I need to figure out a way to reliably access and automate the data in this grid despite the virtualization. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a workaround for this? Any tips or best practices for handling AG Grid with Selenium would be greatly appreciated!
I've tried implementing scrolling to load the data, but this approach makes the overall test flaky and unreliable. I need to figure out a way to reliably access and automate the data in this grid despite the virtualization.

catching Stale Element Exceptions and re-getting webelement reference arrays when caught is a good solution for this.  You'll still need to figure out how much to scroll each time, though.  (which might be a little different on each platform)  Pagination is a much better solution here.  Not sure why you would want to load the whole dataset into front-end like this.
